# How do I override MySQL Case Sensitivity on per database or table base?

Tags: mysql

I keep reading solutions about editing the my.cnf file, however I want case sensitivity on all databases except 1 and editing the my.cnf will change it for all databases.

Is there a way to specifically disable case sensitivity via table insert and/or database creation so I can disable sensitivity either per table or per database instead of across all databases?

I am using mysql, php, and pdo database connections in case that is important to a solution.

Comment: see this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Comment: @Rahul that link, is about system wide changes also. I am specifically asking if this is possible to do without a system wide change to all mysql. I need this to be a per database solution.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no per DB setting present.

Comment: Do you mind writing that up as an answer, maybe include the links that show there is not a per db or per table setting, as that is SPECIFICALLY the question I was asking. I new how to change it system wide, just wasn't just if there was a work around for per instance usage.

Comment: if they ever mark it not duplicate that is.

Comment: `To convert one or more entire databases, dump them before setting lower_case_table_names, then drop the databases, and reload them after setting lower_case_table_names:`-http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @Bruce, I have reversed my vote to close the question as a duplicate. I don't know of any way to make MySQL database names or table names case insensitive on an individual basis. The global config setting is the only option, AFAIK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no per DB setting present. Per [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) you can use `lower_case_table_names` system variable while starting `mysqld` but that as well Global and not a per DB solution which you are looking for. As already commented by @cris85 ... linked documentation also states below alternative

> To convert one or more entire databases, dump them before setting
>   `lower_case_table_names`, then drop the databases, and reload them
>   after setting `lower_case_table_names`:
>
> Use `mysqldump` to dump each database:
>
> ```
> mysqldump --databases db1 > db1.sql
> mysqldump --databases db2 > db2.sql
> ...
> ```
>
> Do this for each database that must be recreated.
>
> Use `DROP DATABASE` to drop each database.
>
> Stop the server, set `lower_case_table_names`, and restart the server.
>
> Reload the dump file for each database. Because
>   `lower_case_table_names` is set, each database and table name will be
>   converted to lowercase as it is recreated:
>
> ```
> mysql < db1.sql
> mysql < db2.sql
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT a solution to the question asked, but is a solution to the problem that brought me to ask this question.

The actual problem I was having was that I have dynamic tables in a database called table_.$username These tables are called when a profile user is accessed.

For for example

```
http://www.myurl.com/profile.php?user=admin
```

would return

```
table_admin
```

The problem was

```
http://www.myurl.com/profile.php?user=Admin
```

would not return the table_admin as it would search for table_Admin which did not exist.

My work around solution was as follows:

```
$user = $_GET['user']
$stmt=$db->prepare('SELECT username FROM members WHERE username = :user');
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $user);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$user = $row['username'];
```

Comment: You could also just set the table name to `'table_' . strtolower($_GET["user"])` in your PHP code, both when you create the table and later when you read the table.

Comment: I like that, that would cut out a bit of overhead from database connections.